# Create unique address per user and get notification of incoming transaction

Tags: json-rpc

With bitcoin I can getnewaddress for a specific user, and then receive a notification when a transfer comes in, which I can use to match to that particular user.  I was wondering how I would go about doing something similar with ethereum.  I'd prefer to use the RPC if possible for as much as it as I can.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean using "getnewaddress" in an API or for example a payment processor? Or where did you use it?

Comment: In the bitcoin api there is a "getnewaddress" command which just generates a new address attached to the same wallet (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list)

Comment: So when I understand correctly, you want to use your ethereum wallet, create a new address and get notified if ethers come in there?

Comment: Yes, each user would have it's own address, it would make a transaction using that address, and then I would be notified of the transaction so I could match it to that user and credit it appropriately.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21626)

Comment: any update yet looking for the same question